# Function within a function, how to call a counter, Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I need to use buttons to call one of two states inside a function, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong because the code is working wrong. The code does "print" because it's a simplified version of the code. How do I correctly make that with "Next" the result is 0, 1, 2... and with "Prev" it is 0, 5, 4, assuming I am moving in a 6 element set. As I have the "Next" function alone, I have the result "Next 1", "Next 2".... As I turn on the "Prev" method, I get "Next 1" "Prev 0",the next step "Next 1" "Prev 0" etc. at the same time. Thank you for your help :D.

```
import tkinter as tk


    class Calc:
        def __init__(self, root, get_save_analize=None, get_prev=None, get_next=None):
            self.root = root
            self.counter = 0
    
            menu = tk.Menu(self.root)
            file_menu = tk.Menu(menu)
            self.root.config(menu=file_menu)
            self.file_menu = menu
    
            filemenu = tk.Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
            helpmenu = tk.Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
    
            file_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    
            # Image
            file_menu.add_command(label="Previous", command=lambda: self.get_my_function(get_prev))  
            file_menu.add_command(label="Next", command=lambda: self.get_my_function(get_next))      

    def get_my_function(self, get_next=None, get_prev=None):

        var = get_next
        vap = get_prev

        def get_next():
            self.counter += 1
            print('next', self.counter)
            return self.counter
        get_next()

        def get_prev():
            self.counter -= 1
            print('prev', self.counter)
            return self.counter
        get_prev()  

app = tk.Tk()
Calc(app).get_my_function()
app.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWglD.png)

Comment: there are countless options to achieve that. Using a global variable for example.

Comment: @Thingamabobs he is already trying to use an internal `counter` attribute on his instance, which is most likely a better approach than a global variable. That also was unrelated to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that the is that currently everytime you call `get_my_function` you end up calling both `get_next` and `get_prev` and your input variables `get_prev` and `get_next` are never used, nor are `var` or `vap`.

Still kind of guessing at what you are trying to do, but here how I got it to work for me if you want to keep as much of your code the same as possible and if you are indeed setting it up so that the get_next and get_prev functions get passed into Calc

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Calc:
    def __init__(self, root, get_save_analize=None, get_prev=None, get_next=None):
        self.root = root
        self.counter = 0

        menu = tk.Menu(self.root)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu)
        self.root.config(menu=file_menu)
        self.file_menu = menu

        filemenu = tk.Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu = tk.Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)

        file_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        # Image
        file_menu.add_command(label="Previous", command=lambda: self.get_my_function(get_prev=get_prev))
        file_menu.add_command(label="Next", command=lambda: self.get_my_function(get_next=get_next))


    def get_my_function(self, get_next=None, get_prev=None):
        var = get_next
        vap = get_prev

        print(f"get_my_func, {var=}, {vap=}")
        if var is not None:
            var() # this is the function get_next which was originally input when Calc was created

            def get_next():
                self.counter += 1
                print('next', self.counter)
                return self.counter

            get_next()

        if vap is not None:
            vap()  # this is the function get_prev which was originally input when Calc was created

            def get_prev():
                self.counter -= 1
                print('prev', self.counter)
                return self.counter

            get_prev()


app = tk.Tk()


def input_get_next():
    print("calling input_get_next (var)")

def input_get_prev():
    print("calling input_get_prev (vap)")

c = Calc(app, get_next=input_get_next, get_prev=input_get_prev)
app.mainloop()
```